# What happens if there’s dialogue in dialogue in dialogue?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks, dialogue

Do you do an apostrophe again, or can you not do it at all? It’s been very confusing for me!

Comment: It might help if you give an example of what you see as the problem.

Comment: In American English you'd use this nesting "A said 'B said "blah blah" ' ". In British English the order of single and double quotes would be swapped.

Comment: Everyone gets confused, of course!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues worth addressing here in responding to your question.

**Apostrophe or quotation mark?**
Note that we use the same *key stroke* (`'`) for both a single quotation mark and an [apostrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe), but as they serve different functions in written text, it's important not to confuse their names. Single quotation marks are **not** apostrophes.

**Single or double?**
For one quoted item, the [preferred usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_marks_in_English#Quotations_and_speech) in the USA, Canada, Australia and New Zealand is the double quotation mark – e.g. *She said "Boo!"* – whereas in Britain and South Africa it's single quotes: *She said 'Boo!'*

Note that standard word-processing software will usually convert these marks into "smart quotes" (looking like supertext sixes and nines). On Stack Exchange you have to manually enter the specific smart quote characters so that the text appears thus: `She said ‘Boo!’` See also [how to type quotation marks on a computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_marks_in_English#Typing_quotation_marks_on_a_computer_keyboard).

**Dialogue within dialogue?**
Both the British and American styles use *nested quotation marks* for dialogue within dialogue, alternating between single and double quotation marks or vice versa, depending on whether you're using the British or American usage to start and end the main quotation. Hence:

> Jana said, “Peter reckons he said ‘Baby says “boo” ’ ”. [American]
>   Jana said, ‘Peter reckons he said “Baby says ‘boo’ ” ’. [British]

**Where does the other punctuation go?**
In both AmE and BritE, punctuation is usually placed where it logically belongs. For example, an exclamation mark goes within the quotation marks containing the exclamation:

> Jana said, “Peter reckons he said ‘Baby says “boo!” ’ ”

However, AmE and BritE differ in placement of periods (full stops) and commas. AmE will normally put the period or comma inside the quotation mark in all cases, whereas BritE puts the punctuation *outside* if the quoted text is a sentence *fragment*. This BritE approach is also called *logical punctuation* because the decision on where to place the period/comma is based on whether it is a logical component of the quoted text. Thus:

> “Peter reckons he said ‘Baby says “boo,” ’ ” Jana explained. [American]
>   ‘Peter reckons he said “Baby says ‘boo’ ” ’, Jana explained. [British]

This is complicated and not central to the current question; for a fuller explanation, see the helpful [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_marks_in_English#Order_of_punctuation).

**[Spacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_marks_in_English#Spacing)**
In an actual typeset publication there would be no space character (as inserted by the spacebar) between the quotation marks; instead, *kerning* would be used to separate the individual quotation marks so that they can be easily distinguished. Without kerning or other spacing, the above example would look confusing:

> Jana said, “Peter reckons he said ‘Baby says “boo”’”.

However, ordinary folk like us typing on a standard keyboard are unlikely to resort to manual kerning. For standard documents it's fine to insert a normal space between two consecutive quotation marks. For documents where a more professional appearance is preferred, you can insert a *non-breaking space* (`&nbsp;`).